# Filter data from an XML document

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following XML file.

```
<JamStatus>
<IPAddress Value="10.210.104.32 " FacId="2">
<Type>Letter</Type>
<JobId>1</JobId>
<fi>50-30C-KMC-360A</fi>
<TimestampPrinting>1309464601:144592</TimestampPrinting>
</IPAddress>
<IPAddress Value="10.210.104.32 " FacId="2">
<Type>Letter</Type>
<JobId>2</JobId>
<fi>50-30C-KMC-360A</fi>
<TimestampPrinting>1309465072:547772</TimestampPrinting>
</IPAddress> 
<IPAddress Value="10.210.104.32 " FacId="2">
<Type>Letter</Type>
<JobId>2</JobId>
<fi>50-30C-KMC-360A</fi>
<TimestampPrinting>1309465072:547772</TimestampPrinting>
</IPAddress>  
</JamStatus>
```

There may be any number of IPaddress elememt in the document. jobid and timestamp can be same for a perticular IPAddress. I want to get the count of ipAddress whose Value, jobid and timestampprinting are same. In this case it is 2. which is the best way to get this information?

Is there any simple method without using LINQ?

Thanks,
syd

Comment: Do you mean the number of `IPAddress` elements whose `Value`, `JobId` and `TimespampPrinting` are the same? Or just the latter two?

Comment: all the three. value,jobid and address

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use LINQ?  Your solution could be expressed easily and succinctly with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XElement and LINQ:

```
            var s = @"
                <JamStatus>
<IPAddress Value=""10.210.104.32 "" FacId=""2"">
<Type>Letter</Type>
<JobId>1</JobId>
<fi>50-30C-KMC-360A</fi>
<TimestampPrinting>1309464601:144592</TimestampPrinting>
</IPAddress>
<IPAddress Value=""10.210.104.32 "" FacId=""2"">
<Type>Letter</Type>
<JobId>2</JobId>
<fi>50-30C-KMC-360A</fi>
<TimestampPrinting>1309465072:547772</TimestampPrinting>
</IPAddress> 
<IPAddress Value=""10.210.104.32 "" FacId=""2"">
<Type>Letter</Type>
<JobId>2</JobId>
<fi>50-30C-KMC-360A</fi>
<TimestampPrinting>1309465072:547772</TimestampPrinting>
</IPAddress>  
</JamStatus>";

            XElement xel = XElement.Parse(s);

            Console.WriteLine(xel.XPathSelectElements("//IPAddress")
                .GroupBy(el => new Tuple<string, string>(el.Element((XName)"JobId").Value, el.Element((XName)"TimestampPrinting").Value))
                .Max(g => g.Count())
            );
```

Comment: LINQ-to-XML and in particular XElement are supported in 3.5

Comment: Net 3.5 doesn't support tuples. Could you suggest any other method?

Comment: well you can use KeyValuePair, or just concatenate the two strings

Comment: Why not just use an anonymous object?

Comment: @syd, it's very easy to add your own `Tuple` to .Net 3.5. But I would go with anonymous objects here probably in 4.0 too.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Linq-to-XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).  If I'm understanding correctly, you want to find the sets of `IPAddress`, `JobId` and `TimestampPrinting` where `JobId` and `TimestampPrinting` are the same.  For that, you need to [group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336754.aspx#simple1) the elements together.